# Django race condition aggregate(Max) in F() expression

Tags: django, aggregate, race-condition

Imagine the following model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # natural PK
    increment = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Increment'), null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    # other fields
```

When an item is created, I want the `increment` fields to automatically acquire the maximum value is has across the whole table, +1. For example:

```
|_item____________________________|
|_id_|_increment__________________|
| 1  | 1                          |
| 2  | 2                          |
| 4  | 3                          | -> id 3 was deleted at some stage..
| 5  | 4                          |
| 6  | 5                          |
.. etc
```

When a new `Item()` comes in and is `saved()`, how in one pass, and in way that will avoid race conditions, make sure it will have increment 6 and not 7 in case another process does exactly the same thing, at the same time?

I have tried:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    i = Item()
    highest_increment = Item.objects.all().aggregate(Max('increment'))
    i.increment = highest_increment['increment__max']
    i.save()
```

I would like to be able to create it in a way similar to the following, but that obviously does not work (have checked places like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f):

```
from django.db.models import Max, F
i = Item(
   increment=F(Max(increment))
)
```

Many thanks

Comment: Tried this out and I get `F() expressions can only be used to update, not to insert.`. Are you getting this as well? It seems you have to create the object first and update the max increment with + 1 after

Comment: yeah getting this too. So maybe create, then do the update. Fine. But that does not solve the problem of "when updating" make sure increment is Max(increment)[across all rows]+1.